# clearInterval variable name continually called but comes up not defined

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to loop until a document object appears in the DOM. This idea is a backup to `window.onload` without using Jquery or another framework, but annoyingly after a few hours now I can't see what's wrong with my function declaration and such.

I've played around with this for far too long a time now (trying to make use of [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987941/clearinterval-and-scope)) and am just asking for help on here as a last resort, else I give up on it. Debugging it to the console shows that it never enters the second loop. I'd really like to understand the scope at work here but looking around questions on this site I can't see any in-depth explanations of how to bring things "out" of a loop, as I'm used to doing with `return` statements and defining global variables.

I am clearly misunderstanding something, as the `loadingLoop()` function works, but doesn't loop on its own! If I run it in the console manually it'll have the desired effect (replacing a video element for a GIF as a simple browser fallback).

```
 function vid1() { return document.getElementById("id13") }
 function vid2() { return document.getElementById("id12") }

 function loadingLoop() { 
     console.log("loading...");
   setTimeout(function(){

        if(typeof vid1() === "object"){
    var vid1gif = document.createElement('img');
        vid1gif.setAttribute("src","...gif");
        vid1gif.setAttribute("style",vid1().getAttribute("style"));
        return document.getElementById("body_layer").replaceChild(vid1gif, vid1()); 
            loadingLoop()
        }
// Never gets here

        if(typeof vid2() === "object"){
        var vid2gif = document.createElement('img');
        vid2gif.setAttribute("src","...gif");
        vid2gif.setAttribute("style","height: 230px; left: 662px; position: absolute; top: 698px; z-index: 1;");
        return function makeChange() {document.getElementById("body_layer").replaceChild(vid2gif, vid2());};
}

        else {
        console.log("grr...");
            loadingLoop();

   }}, 300);

}
```

If I'm making fundamental errors it's probably a good idea to have them brought to light sooner rather than later. I still class myself as fairly new to this language and advice on my code structure would be fantastic.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for setInterval() instead of setTimeout()

Comment: the link I posted describes how `setTimeout()` is a better choice. For the record, I tried both

Comment: Well you also have a return statement before you call loadingLoop() again in your first if clause (so the loop won't actually get called).